# simple javascript frontend for node.js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, backend, project

I am preparing a curriculum for a JavaScript course for a local in-person class hosted by a local non-profit. I have been given an outline of the course that is apparently approved by the Dept of Education. The outline simply has the topics and subtopics listed, but no actual substance. It is my job to create presentations and projects off this outline.

The outline includes coverage of Node.js. It does not include any JavaScript frameworks such as Vue, React or Angular. I don't know view but am somewhat familiar with React and Angular, though I don't know if I know enough to teach it. Moreover, I don't think I would have course time available to teach those, given what else needs to be covered.

Moreover, I learned Node.js back in 2019 in college but have not used it since. I definitely need to brush up on it, which I don't think will be too difficult.

But here's the problem. I need to create a Node project for the students to do. I'm sure I could come up with a fairly simple idea that I could flesh out on the backend. But I don't know what to do about a frontend, since we wouldn't be using React, Vue or Angular.  In college we used Angular as a frontend.

Can a frontend for a Node.js app be created from just HTML, CSS and vanilla JavaScript? What would that look like? Or do I need some sort of framework for a frontend? And if so, what would be some simple frontend JavaScript frameworks that I could maybe figure out quickly and then teach to students relatively quickly? (Side question: can Vue be picked up easily and quickly so I could wedge it in without taking too much time from the official course outline?)

If this question belongs on another board, please tell me the board and I will move it.

Thanks!

Comment: You can create an ajax based call that updates your displayed page based your node backend without using any frameworks. It the most simple form, this may be best to teach first anyways. I would suggest posting the outline you describe, this is kind of a hard question for SO

Answer (score -1):

> Can a frontend for a Node.js app be created from just HTML, CSS and vanilla JavaScript?

Yes. There are several ways to do that.

Perhaps the simplest solution would be to use a server. Something like https://github.com/chcunningham/atomics-post-message/blob/main/server.js should work as a generic Node.js server with no external dependencies.

Another option is to use Native Messaging, which provides a means to communicate with `node` from the browser https://github.com/guest271314/native-messaging-nodejs (I am the author of this code).

Yet another, slightly more involved option, is to use `fs.watchFile` to interact with `node` from the browser, essentially creating a FIFO socket or STDIO using writes and reads to local files https://github.com/guest271314/fs/blob/main/nodejs (I am the author of this code, too).

All of the above options use only the `node` executable standalone; no packages or external dependencies, no frameworks or libraries; nor even a `package.json` file or `node_modules` folder are necessary to run.